# Conky overlapping itself when switching between desktops

Tags: 14.04, conky

I'm running into a problem with my conky setup. It works perfectly fine as long as I'm not trying to switch to a second desktop. The moment I do that is when conky starts to overlap itself. Looks like before writing the updated information the old lines are not removed so it simply stacks everything on top of the old lines. Quite the eyesore ...

I'm starting conky via "Startup applications" with a 30 seconds delay (`conky -p30`).

To see my config file look here: https://github.com/sebastian9486/kobol-configurations/blob/master/conky/.conkyrc

Anybody already experienced this behavior? I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance guys. Best regards, Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

On line 11 change:

```
own_window_type override
```

to:

```
own_window_type normal
```

if that doesn't work, then try `desktop` instead of `normal`.

As per similar problems at ([ubuntuforums.org - Conky overlapping everything](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1521231)).

On my own system I use `normal` without any problems however Conky stays on the internal monitor and I don't move it to the external display. Indeed I'm not even sure I know what you mean by "switching desktops". I did use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> logged into console and then switched back to GUI with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> if that's what you meant.

Comment: Using type normal, conky doesn't render itself "within" my desktop but in a separate window which (as any other window) is closeable via x-icon. Type desktop hides/removes all conky information when I do anything on my desktop. What I want is my conky to be part of ("in") my desktop without overlapping itself. As for switching desktops: I'm using the icon you see here http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-z2wVD7iJy4k/Ulk-OOL50qI/AAAAAAAAFHA/YTd77lSWUZg/s1000/cairo-dock-1.jpg on the bottom left (right above the trash bin) to toggle between different instances / window-sets or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: Try adding `own_window_argb_visual yes`... Sorry there is a lot of stuff to try and this could take awhile.

Comment: In the meantime I tried some completely new conky configs but I'm still stuck with this issue. So I reverted back to my original config. Does anyone have an idea? To visualize my problem I uploaded a screenshot of my conky just mo make sure everybody understands what I mean by saying conky "overlaps itself".

Find config and screen here https://github.com/sebastian9486/kobol-configurations/tree/master/conky

Comment: This conky was up and running for about 8 hours today ...

I also checked if I accidentally was running two conky processess at the same time. ```ps x | grep conky ``` returned nothing suspicious. 

`sebastian@kobol:~$ ps x | grep conky
 2441 ?        Sl     0:52 conky -p30
16829 pts/2    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto conky
`